# Programmaticaly hide post information

Tags: nodes

I would like to programmatically hide the post information.

I don't know where the author name and the creation date is stored in the database, but I would like to hide them.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

i find....

```
variable_set('node_submitted_'.$my_content_type, false);
```

Comment: hi wall-e please consider the solution as said by Bustikiller

Comment: If prefer this solution to the one posted by Bustikiller. Using the node.tpl.phjp template means that you either hide the information for all content types, or that you will use different node templates per content type, just to hide the information. Leading to lots of duplicated code (bad for maintenance).

Answer (score 3):

You can use an implementation of [`hook_preprocess_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) to set `$display_submitted` variables used in (good practices following) node templates to control whether or not to display the information.

```
function XYZ_preprocess_node() {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $variables['display_submitted'] &= ($node->type != 'content-type')
}
```

Where `XYZ` is the name of a custon module or theme, and`content-type` is the machine name of the content you want to hide the publishing information for.

Comment: This is preferable to altering the template theme.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the following lines in your theme `node.tpl.php` template:

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
    <div class="meta submitted">
      <?php print $user_picture; ?>
      <?php print $submitted; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It would be much preferable to use a different template file for that content type, instead of altering the template file used for every node. Also, this solution is not something that can be done programmatically.